# EXCEL VBA : Loop is working but not refreshing before printing to PDF file

Tags: excel, vba, loops, pdf-generation, refresh

Good Morning everybody!

I have an issue concerning my VBA Code. I actualy just want to create a loop that prints PDFs that are based on the same background template (which is in the sheet called AFFIDAVIT CREATOR) replacing some 4 boxes (labels and images) from the INPUT Sheet.

So far, the loop is working properly. Only problem:
It generates the PDF files according to the given name (variable r) but refreshes the sheet AFTER exporting to PDF. Result: Mutliple files with different names but they all display the same :(

Any ideas?

That's my code:

```
Private Sub TryMe()
Dim r As Long
Dim strCap As String
Dim strCap2 As String
r = 4

    Do Until Sheets("INPUT").Cells(r, 3).Value = ""

    strCap = Sheets("INPUT").Cells(r, 3).Value
    Sheets("AFFIDAVIT CREATOR").Label1.Caption = strCap

strCap2 = Sheets("INPUT").Cells(r, 5).Value
Sheets("AFFIDAVIT CREATOR").Label2.Caption = strCap2

If Sheets("INPUT").Cells(r, 4) = "OE" Then
    Sheets("AFFIDAVIT CREATOR").Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OE_Logo.jpg")
Else
    Sheets("AFFIDAVIT CREATOR").Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\SF_Logo.jpg")
End If

If Sheets("INPUT").Cells(r, 6) = "OE" Then
    Sheets("AFFIDAVIT CREATOR").Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OE_Logo.jpg")
Else
    Sheets("AFFIDAVIT CREATOR").Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\SF_Logo.jpg")
End If


ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, From:=1, To:=1, FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheets("INPUT").Cells(r, 3) & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Sheets("AFFIDAVIT CREATOR").Calculate

r = r + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: what for you have this line `Sheets("AFFIDAVIT CREATOR").Calculate` and why it isn't before `.ExportAsFixedFormat ...`??

Comment: It actually is/was. I even did a childish thing and copy-pasted it 20 times all over the code and it is not working. It is still refreshing after printing all the pages! Even tried that: `If Sheets("AFFIDAVIT CREATOR").Calculate Then ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, From:=1, To:=1, FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheets("INPUT").Cells(r, 3) & ".pdf" _ , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _ :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False Else Sheets("AFFIDAVIT CREATOR").Calculate End If`

Comment: I don't know why it's happening but try the following tests: B) insert `Stop` before you `.ExportAsFixedFormat` to check if pictures are loaded after a few sec, if so run the sub further by pressing F5 in IDE. B) what if you move `.ExportAsFixedFormat` to separate `Sub onlyExport()` and call it from current one in the same place like `Call onlyExport`...

Comment: When I stop it is refreshing after 3 seconds or so.
Isolating it to a seperated sub is not working, I wlready tried that :(
Any idea of what I could to except call a wait function (that solution didn't work)

Comment: I'll give you temporary answer... it's to long to put in comments...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to comments, if `Stop` worked in the way that you need approx. 3 sec to get your picture loaded you could try to use a `wait workaround` which looks as follow:

```
Dim Start As Single
Start = Timer
'wait 5 sec...
Do While Start + 5 > Timer
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Add the code just before `.ExportAsFixedFormat`. Above I set waiting time to 5 sec. which you could change after some tests.

Comment: Works perfectly with a delay of 0.5 seconds. It slows down the process but it's better than no process at all!

Comment: Nice solution! This suggests the Loadpicture command runs in its own thread... I wonder if there is a way to "wait for it to finish" rather than wait a fixed time. @KazJaw - do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Floris, unfortunately, if I knew I'd post it here as answer... But I can admit, I didn't make max effort to search for something which you described.

Comment: @Floris 
Yes it works to generate PDFs. Unfortunately it doesn't work for a regular printing method (crashed after the first page...)

Comment: @YannickHelmut can you update your question to show "a regular printing method"? It would be good if you made the code as simple as possible. Change one cell, print (rather than the whole affidavit formatting thing). Usually when you reduce the code to the minimum that reproduces the error, the solution presents itself...

Comment: ++ Nice! Just came here from another post