# VBA for Excel macro no longer works correctly under Windows 10

Tags: excel, vba

The VBA text is as follows:

```
Sub GET_PF()
'
' GET_PF Macro
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Portfolio Mobile\Share Control Revalued 2016.xlsm"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Portfolio Mobile\Share Control UK Revalued 2016.xlsm"
End Sub
```

It was ok under Windows 7 and still works perfectly in debug mode when I step into it. When it runs automatically the second workbook does not load. I tried reversing the workbooks to no avail. Can I build a wait of some sort in? It has to be a timing issue!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936818/pause-code-execution-but-let-excel-work

Comment: Please post back if the delay helps.  I have a routine that loops through a small list of files and opens most of them (about 15 or so).  The loop induces minimal delay (merely comparing the file name against a simple mask), and I've not had any problem opening any of the files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wait function in vba
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213656%28office.11%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks that helped. Your code was not correct for the version I am using. However the standard from the Microsoft library did.
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
At 1 second it did not work even in debug mode, and at 2 seconds it sometimes worked and sometimes did not. So I ended up with 5 seconds.
However, even now it is not perfect - it works when I select and run the macro, but only loads the first one when I use a shortcut.
I did try changing the shortcut, but had to put it back because the one I chose (CTRL+Shift+"L"), not flagged as occupied, but did something else!